# Setting date parameters and then establishing amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables I'm trying to put together that's proving to be kind of tricky for me. My two tables are `weeks` and `transactions`; the following query is what I have created to show all new customers based on the first time they had a transactions with us:

```
WITH newPat AS
(
    SELECT 
        clinic, patient_id, MIN(date_entered) AS np_date
    FROM 
        transactions
    WHERE 
        impacts = 'P'
    GROUP BY 
        clinic, patient_id
)
SELECT 
    n.clinic, COUNT(n.patient_id) AS new_pats, 
    n.np_date, w.start_week, w.week_id, w.wk_year
FROM 
    newPat n
INNER JOIN 
    weeks w ON (n.np_date BETWEEN w.start_week AND w.end_week)
GROUP BY 
    n.clinic, n.np_date, w.start_week, w.week_id, w.wk_year
```

So the `WITH` is determining the start date for each `patient_id` unique to the `clinic`. Then using that information, determining which `week_id` of a given `wk_year` they made that transaction. This by itself works.

The trouble that I also need to pull `amount` from the transaction table for those `patient_id` for the given week they were new. Can't try pulling 'amount' within the WITH else it creates multiple entries as "new" due to amounts being different. There would be multiple entries for a given `patient_id` on the same dates with varying `amount` as this table shows individual services even if they fall onto the same transaction number (`tran_num`) So what would be the best method to find this data?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION: Thanks for the quick comments, the transaction ID can occur again if there are any adjustments made to it down the road. I like the idea of the partition but I do need more than the first row as there can be multiple rows for the same transaction and date. I'm fairly new to SQL so I could be missing something simple. But, essentially I need to `(SUM(amount) WHERE date_entered = MIN(date_entered))` and where the `patient_id AND clinic` are unique.

Comment: Why don't you sum the amounst `SUM` in the with clause so that they are aggregated? Or am I not understanding the requirement here.

Comment: I think instead of a SUM of all amounts, he wants the single amount of the earliest row by date for that clinic, patient_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your CTE with this:

```
WITH newPat AS(
SELECT clinic, patient_id, date_entered AS np_date, amount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clinic, patient_id ORDER BY date_entered ASC) AS rn
FROM transactions
WHERE impacts='P'
 )
```

and then add `WHERE rn = 1` to your main query.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Tab suggested, this is the end result that seemed to work:

```
WITH newPat AS(
SELECT clinic, patient_id, date_entered AS np_date, SUM(amount) AS total,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clinic, patient_id ORDER BY date_entered ASC) AS rn
FROM transactions
WHERE impacts='P'
GROUP BY clinic, patient_id, date_entered)
SELECT n.clinic, n.patient_id, n.np_date, w.start_week, w.week_id, w.wk_year, n.total
FROM newPat AS n INNER JOIN
dbo.weeks AS w ON n.np_date BETWEEN w.start_week AND w.end_week
WHERE n.rn=1
```

Adding in the SUM(amount) aggregated function to get the overall I was looking for